# Is my series convergence test valid?

Tags: convergence-divergence

Whilst reading through and attempting some other questions here on Math.SE, I hit upon an idea for testing whether a series is convergent, and I'd like to know:

1. If it is a valid test
2. How practical this test may be to use?

I'll summarise it briefly here:
$$\text{For a function}\space f(n), \text{it's infinite sum }\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{f(n)}\space\text{is convergent if}$$
$$\exists\rho>0\text{ such that} \space\forall n>\rho; f(n)\ge10f(n+1) $$
In essence, the thought process becomes apparent when we examine the trivial $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{10^{-n}}$$
For which $f(n)=10f(n+1)$ and we have $f(1)=0.1, f(2)=0.01, f(3)=0.001$, and so forth, with obvious convergence to $\frac{10}{9}$.

As a more complicated example, I tried $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{n^3}{n!}}$$ and upon use of my test I generated:
$$\frac{n^3}{n!}\ge\frac{10(n+1)^3}{(n+1)!}\to n^3(n+1)\ge 10(n+1)^3\to(n+1)[n^3-10(n+1)^2]\ge0$$
Iterating $n_{t+1}=\sqrt[3]{10(n_t+1)^2}$ gives us $\rho\approx11.77122803$, and testing $n=12$ confirms the inequality is satisfied for $n>\rho$, thus there is convergence.

I'd like to know your thoughts on this method.

Comment: Why use $10$?  You could have used any number $r>1$ and arrived at the same conclusion with the examples you cited.  And if you replace $f(n)>rf(n+1)$ with $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{f(n)}{f(n+1)}\right|\ge r>1$, you have the ratio test.

Comment: I picked $10$ due to the idea that the first value in a number will jump back a space each time (or more) and thus convergence is certain. The $10^{-n}$ example displays that beautifully in my opinion.

Comment: Try another number such as $2$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

As stated, the test is incorrect without assuming that $f(n)$ is nonnegative.  A counterexample is $f(n) = -1$ for all $n$.

With the additional assumption, this is a weak form of the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test). Note that the ratio test implies that $10$ may be replaced by $1 + \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a special case of the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).